# How to open a new connection in mysql-workbench from the command line

Tags: mysql, command-line, mysql-workbench

I have used mysql-workbench on both Windows and Linux (Ubuntu) for a while now, and I find it's interface very comfortable, so when I needed a good GUI MySQL client to integrate with my code this was the obvious choice.

My MySQL connections parameters are saved in my server (IP, user, password) and I want to use these paremeters to open a mysql-workbench query window.

I read the command line arguments help (I use version 6.0) and it seems I can open a specific connection by it's name, but I want the code to be independent of my saved connections as I trust the connection info from my server more than one saved in mysql-workbench.

Is there an option to connect to an "anonymous" connection, or to create/manipulate connections from the shell (in either Windows or Linux)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such feature. Always use the connection name. If you want you can create a feature request at http://bugs.mysql.com to get attention for your wish.